# useEffect: not rendering after update of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a list of items (I get the items with a GET-call - I didn't add it here, because I think it's irrelevant). When I delete an item, the list should be updated/ re-rendered.

To do this I use the useEffect-hook with a second parameter (productData).

**Problem:**
I have to refresh the page manually in order to see the new list of items. I don't understand why: I use useEffect with the second parameter. Could someone point me in the right direction what is wrong? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
export default function MemberSavedProducts() {

  const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]); 
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {}, [productData]);

  const deleteProduct = async(prod) => {
    try {
      if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?")) {
        const {
          data
        } = await fetchContext.authAxios.delete(
          `savedProducts/${prod}`
        );
        setProductData(
          productData.filter((prod) => prod !== data.deletedItem.Id)
        );
        setSuccessMessage(data.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      const {
        data
      } = err.response;
      setErrorMessage(data.message);
    }
  };

  return (
      <CardLarge>
        <div className={styles.productWrapper}>
          {successMessage && <SuccessMessage text={successMessage} />}
          {errorMessage && <ErrorMessage text={errorMessage} />}

          {productData.map((prod) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={prod.id}
              >
                <ProductItem
                  prod={prod}
                  onClick={() => {
                     getInfo(prod.information);
                  }}
                 />
                 <button
                   onClick={() => {deleteProduct(prod.Id)}}
                 >
                   Delete
                 </button>
               </div>
             );
           })}
         </div>
      </CardLarge>
```

);
}

Comment: Are you sure the filter function works? It seems the refresh works because the GET response returns the right array. I think it should be `productData.filter((prod) => prod.Id !== data.deletedItem.Id));` or use the passed parameter instead of the response maybe like this `productData.filter((p) => p.Id !== prod));`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking look at the code! @Stutje: You were right. This was an issue with the filter, not useEffect. What a silly mistake...took me hours! Now it's working..Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussed this in the comments, posting this answer for completeness.

Are you sure the filter function works? It seems the refresh works because the GET response returns the right array. I think it should be `productData.filter((prod) => prod.Id !== data.deletedItem.Id));`. Because in your code you are comparing an object to a string.

Or you can use the passed parameter `prod` instead of the response maybe like this `productData.filter((p) => p.Id !== prod));`

Also a small clarification: `useEffect` does not cause a rerender, changing state does trigger a rerender. `useEffect` is just a listener/callback that triggers on change of the declared dependencies.